# Unclude fragment from Backstack using Navigation component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have Fragments X, A, B, and i'm using Navigation architecture component to navigate between them.

Fragments A, B specific, but Fragment X can be any(C,D,...);

Fragments A and B from Bottom Navigation and their "navigations icons" always on the screen, it means user can go to A or B anytime from any Fragment(include A and B):

---

`X -> A -> B`

`X -> B -> A`

`A -> B -> X`

`A -> B -> A`

`//another ways`

---

My problem about this case:

`X -> A -> B -> A -> B -> ?`

If user started from `X`, reached `?` and begin to go back by "back" button, he goes throw `A`,`B` several times:

**User pressed back:**

`? -> B -> A -> B -> A -> X`

But I want "to exclude" fragments from backstack if they already on it:

`? -> A -> B -> X`

If user navigate:

`X -> A -> B -> A`

I want to see:

`A -> B -> X`

Not:

`A -> B -> A -> X`

I'm trying to do it with Pop To, but it can return me on one one concrete Fragment only. I need to return on my started X Fragment, not hardcoded. Inclusive and Single top is not about it.

I'm not sure i can do it with basic Navigation component, so i need your advice. If i can't do it, what way should i use? Is there any good practices about it?

---

**UPD:**

I'm using global points to navigate between Fragments. It's how my navigation looks like:

[image]

The right|bottom chain is X, i can navigate from any of it to to not chanied fragments using bottom navigation. It's **Single Activity app**, to navigate i'm using just:

```
   //Using global points
   findNavController(R.id.host).navigate(R.id.toLibrary)
```

Comment: did you get answer ? or i do help you.

Comment: No, i was't. It will be great if you help.

Comment: sure.but let me read carefully your question.no worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following Solution employs **Fragment Visibility Technique** in order to Manage Fragments `Backstack` when `onBackPressed()`.

### at first step

We Assign a Tag to each `Fragment` when it's Called & Invoked to make it possible to Recognize which of `Fragment`s have been Added to `Backstack` and are  *predecessors*.
by below code, we assign a tag to a `Fragment` that is going to be Transacted.

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder, Fragment_A OR Fragment_B OR Fragment_ANY, "A or B or ANY")
.addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

*Remember you must assign a tag to any Fragment that you want to be Transacted*.

### In the second

We are going to Handling `public void onBackPressed()`.

You **MUST** ignore `super.onBackPressed()` Because, we don't Want to *defualt* `onBackPressed` Method to Impact Backstack(as it is) while back button is pressed. Moreover, we Want to Handle Backstack ourselves.

Here you go

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isVisible("A")) { //Go some where else you wanna go }
    else if(isVisible("B")){ //Go some where else you wanna go }
    else if(isVisible("X or any"){ //Go some where else you wanna go }
    else { //Go default page }
}


public boolean isVisible(String tag){
    try {
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

When back button is pressed, We check which `Fragment` is already Visible and do Redirect the user to the Corresponding Predecessor `Fragment`.

For Ex: `A - > B`  OR `A -> X` OR `X -> B`

I am using this Technique for a Released Application and all good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good, but i need time to test it carefull, bacause your propose is broken a lot on my current logic. I have single activity app, so i have some problems about `onBackPressed()` handle, or with Fragment visibility check. I'l test it and write about results. =)

Comment: @KirstenLy i did test it with single activity app and worked well.any problem feel free to share with me .

Answer (score 0):

In fragmentTransaction instead of using addToBackStack() or add(...) use fragmentTransaction.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)

Comment: Oh, i'm not using `fragmentTransaction`. I'm added more info to question.