# How to handle backstack between fragments and viewpagers?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, back-stack, onbackpressed

I am using a ViewPager having 2 pages. First page of that ViewPager is MainFragment. MainFragment has ViewPager as `bottomNavigationView`. Each page has a `FragmentContainerView` and By default they contains HomeFragment, CommunityFragment and NotificationFragment respectively.

This is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Srt9930/BackStackProblemSample) and this is the [APK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4j0xy2nmevy7d3/app-debug.apk?dl=0) of the project. So you can test it and improve it easily.

Now if i am in HomeFragment and I click on a profile button so It transact to ProfileFragment and from there setting and so on. And on clicking on back button it get back perfectly one-by-one. But it does not happens same with other `FragmentContainerView`. Even they get back directly to the parent fragment. Overall i am unable to handle the backstack between different ViewPagers and fragments.

To avoid the confusion of `FragmentContainers` i transact it like this

```
val containerId = (view?.parent as ViewGroup).id
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.add(containerId, profileFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
```

Now the handling of BackPressed() in MainActivity is here

```
if (view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem == 0)
{
    if (view_pager_main_fragment?.currentItem == 0)
    {
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_home)
        val appbarHome = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appbar_home)
        val layoutManager = recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        when {
            layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
            supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0 -> {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
            }
            else -> {
                layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)
                appbarHome.setExpanded(true)
                //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        view_pager_main_fragment?.setCurrentItem(view_pager_main_fragment.currentItem - 1, false)
    }
}
else
{
    // Otherwise, select the previous step.
    view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem = view_pager_main_activity.currentItem - 1
}
```

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55780523/6071729, I suggested a good solution though It may to fully compatible with your specific problem. you can try it.

Comment: I read your answer there but it looks much different, here we also have 2 viewpagers.  And i observe that when viewpager's position is in 1st page it works perfect. This means problem is in backstack with viewpager. So we have to create a well planned backpress event for backstack for every fragment and position of vp.

Comment: Do you use NavigationUI in your project? Because it has the possibility to find a "NavController" (that manages stack of Frames inside a single "NavHostFragment") and then you can navigate or return_to_prev using "navigateTo()" and "navigateUp()" methods.

Comment: I didn't use that and never used it so I don't know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and the problem was the usage of

```
supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

If you read the description of the flag `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` it says:

> If set, and the name or ID of a back stack entry has been supplied,
> then all matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't
> match is found or the bottom of the stack is reached.  Otherwise, all
> entries up to but not including that entry will be removed.

So it was removing the multiple entries at once.

The reason it worked for Home screen was that it never reached that case. It always went in the first case of:

```
layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 -> {
                        super.onBackPressed()
                    }
```

And that's what you exactly need for your case just call `super.onBackPressed()` when you want to pop only one fragment at once. So your final code becomes like this:

In your MainActivity's `onBackPressed()`

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem == 0) {
            if (view_pager_main_fragment?.currentItem == 0) {
                val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.listRecyclerView)
                val appbarHome = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appbar_home)
                val layoutManager = recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                when {
                    layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 -> {
                        super.onBackPressed()
                    }
                    //This is never reached. It can be removed
                    supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0 -> {
                        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(
                            null,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
                        )
                    }
                    else -> {
                        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0)
                        appbarHome.setExpanded(true)
                        //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
                    }
                }
            } else if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0) {
                super.onBackPressed()
            } else {
                // Otherwise, select the previous step.
                view_pager_main_fragment?.setCurrentItem(
                    view_pager_main_fragment.currentItem - 1,
                    false
                )
            }
        } else if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount != 0) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            view_pager_main_activity?.currentItem = view_pager_main_activity.currentItem - 1
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1: From the comments**

> I want to clear the backstack when bottom nav selection changes.

If you want to clear the selection when you change the bottom navigation selection changes then you've to set a listener and clear the back stack in your `MainFragment` as following:

```
view?.bottomNavView?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            //check if item is being re-selected then just return and don't do anything
            if (bottomNavView.selectedItemId == item.itemId){
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
            }
            //if the bottom nav item selection changes then clear the back stack of previous tab
            parentFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)

            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.homeFragment -> viewPager2.setCurrentItem(0, false)
                R.id.searchFragment -> viewPager2.setCurrentItem(1, false)
                R.id.notificationsFragment -> viewPager2.setCurrentItem(2, false)
            }
            true
        }
```

And the rest can remain same. Try this out and do let me know.

Comment: It's just wow! Thank you so much for this amazing answer. I never thought about that line. Now it is working very well But it still has a problem That suppose "i open the app now i navigate to the notification frag and there i open profile frag or other frag. Then i navigate to homeFrag and now if i click on back button so it removes the fragment in the background and when all they get removed then it finally get destroyed. Please Help!

Comment: @Stackoverflower so as I understand. You want to clear the back-stack of that tab when you switch the tab? e.g Notification -> Post -> Profile -> Settings. Now when you click on home it should not have that back-stack. It should clear that stack and when `OnBackPressed` is called after that app should finish directly?

Comment: @Stackoverflower check out my edit. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i'm sorry but it is same  :(  , I tried by pasting this     supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)          in              layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()    and    it worked, But i just have to click back one more time.

Comment: Actually you have to paste this in `MainFragment` `view?.bottomNavView?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` not in main activity. Did you try that?

Comment: Now there is one more problem that if i use viewPager.currentItem - 1  for backstack in viewpager then i also go to those fragment which are not even create yet like "i open the app, Navigate to notification frag then press back and it goes through Notification>Search>Home . So  by this way search fragment creates which is not good for the app.

Comment: Yes i have tried in MainFragment but it did not worked so i tried with MainActivity and it worked. NO NO NO it did not worked in a case if i come back from profile.

Comment: I would suggest that you go back to the basic what was working before my edit. The working answer. Start debugging from there. Or just upload your current code(with issues & my edits) to the github project link which you provided in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231003/discussion-between-mayur-gajra-and-stackoverflower).